# Powershell: UPnP ContentDirectory Browser does not return any results

Tags: powershell, upnp

I want to browse my media server (MiniDLNA 1.1.5 on Rasperry Pi).
Here is the code I have so far:

```
$DeviceFinder = New-Object -COM "UPnP.UPnPDeviceFinder"
$DeviceType = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1"

Write-Host "Finding MediaServer devices..."
$Devices = $DeviceFinder.FindByType($DeviceType,0)
$MediaServer = $Devices | Where-Object { $_.FriendlyName -like "*LittlePi*" }

$MediaServerDirectory = $MediaServer.Services | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ContentDirectory" }

Write-Host "MediaServer Description:" $MediaServer.Description
Write-Host "Browsing MediaServer..."

$ContainerID = 0
$BrowseFlag = "BrowseDirectChildren"
$Filter = ""
$StartIndex = 0
$RequestedCount = 1000
$SortCriteria = ""
$myInObject = @($ContainerID, $BrowseFlag, $Filter, $StartIndex, $RequestedCount, $SortCriteria)
$outArgs = @()

$returnValue = $MediaServerDirectory.InvokeAction("Browse", $myInObject, [ref]$outArgs)
```

My problem is that `$returnValue` and `$outArgs` are `$null`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting $outArgs = $null before you call the InvokeAction?

I had an issue trying to get the external IP address from my router and the $null assignment trick worked.

(search for the 3 keywords: powershell com upnp to see my example)

Not sure if this will have any effect on $returnvalue.